# how can i show only iframe when click on the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Following is my code, I want to make a search list that will show results of you tube and then when i click on the URL, the video start on the same page along with the searching results, but i only want the iframe.

```
    <head>
    <title>Youtube playlist search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 2.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>

    <script src="http://www.yvoschaap.com/ytpage/ytembed.js"></script>

      <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" onsubmit="ytEmbed.init({'block':'youtubeDivSearch','type':'search','q':document.getElementById('ytSearchField').value,'results': 20,'meta','_self':false}); return false;">
      <span>YouT </span>

<input type="text" id="ytSearchField" placeholder="Search your Video Here" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"> 
<input type="submit" value="  Search">
</form>
<div id="youtubeDivSearch"></div>
```

Comment: You could use the youtube API, and get the ID from the selected video, and insert it with an embeded youtube video perhaps?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/documentation/

Comment: youtube API is already used and it works properly, only thing is to categorized it, when it shows the reults then i click on any video, the video will start on the same page alongwith the presviously searched results, buit i want the video Iframe will be alone, not with the search results

Comment: Thanku so much, Work is done